# SImpler way to render text as html

Tags: scala.js

I maybe overlooking a function. In order to render text such as `<div>test</div` as html inside another tag, I would need several lines of code to name the outside tag, then set `.innerHtml`, then return the outside tag. Is there a shorter way? There are also confusing conversions with `.render` with this method.

ex.

```
val content = span(color := "blue").render
content.innerHtml = "<div>test</test>" // html is escaped
outsideTag.innerHtml = content.outerHtml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Scalatags here, you may be looking for [the `raw()` function](http://www.lihaoyi.com/scalatags/#Auto-escapingandunsanitizedInput)...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know scala.js that well, but as far as I understand it, a div tag is added to a span tag.
You should only add inline tags to other inline tags. So it's not a good idea to add a div to a span.

I think imho you can write:

```
outsideTag.innerHtml="<div color='blue'>test</div>";
```